# Embedding XML in a SVN message (comment)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I would like to embed some XML tags into the -m field when I check files in. We are automatically committing files into SVN. I would like to embed some additional information in the -m field, so that when I execute "svn log --xml" I can easily pull my information out.  When I tried this

```
-m "<XYZ> <UserId> 1234 </UserId> </BLM>"
```

the resulting XML file had this instead

> `<msg>&lt;XYZ&gt; &lt;UserId&gt;1234&lt;/UserId&gt;&lt;/XYZ&gt;</msg>`

.

So apparently SVN is thinking for me.

When I use Tortoise to look at the log message it appears correctly.

Another part of this 'problem' is that we can not use SharpSVN, as it is GNU licensed.  We cannot use SVNCOM, as it is GNU licensed.  I tried libGit2 but it would not complete the unit tests. We are using Tortoise in development, but not in the product we are creating.

We are creating simple batch files with a few SVN statements on the fly and executing them. For the most part this has worked ok.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Tortoise is behaving correctly here. It's translating your characters internally into HTML entities, and translating them back correctly when you view it in Tortoise, but from the command line you don't get the translation. Try piping the output through a translator tool such as Recode (http://recode.progiciels-bpi.ca/index.html)

```
$ svn log --xml | recode html..ascii
```

That should get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but it looks like recode is licensed under GNU, so as with the rest of the tools I tried, it is off limits.  But I think you have pointed me in the right direction, just make a program that exchanges the &lt; and &gt; into < >. Then the file will look like normal XML to the next tool.

Comment: It turns out that XMLTextReader will convert those characters into "XML" for me. Then I can send that string to a new XmlReader and traverse the nodes.